# jquery dom object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have a textarea with contents of html file. The textarea content includes my entire html page content, includes the doctype, head, html etc.

now, i want to save the textarea into a dom vairable via $.parseHTML:

```
var txt = $.parseHTML($("textarea").val(), null, true);
```

next, i change my `txt` variable and dom elements with commands like:

```
$(txt).find("h1").text("demo");
$(txt).find("h2").text("demo h2");
```

after changing the txt dom i want to put the txt as string back to the textarea, but nothing seems to work. i already tried:

```
$("textarea").val($(txt).html());
```

or

```
$("textarea").val(txt.html());
```

i also tried looping the dom:

```
$.each($(txt).get(),function(){
    v = $("textarea").val();
    $("textarea").val(v+$(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

but that didn't gave the expected results as items outside the body tag haven't translated back.

any advise shall be greatly appriciated

Comment: try `JSON.stringify($("textarea").val(v+$(this)[0].outerHTML));`

Comment: that's gives "undefined" for text like

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

Comment: @sd1sd1 Just to get clarification on your question do your text area contains HTML file that needs to be saved as variable

Comment: my textarea contain the contents of html file that i want to modify and than save the file again

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $('#textarea').val();
var html = $('<div class="wrap">'+txt+'</div>');
$('h1', html).text('is H1');
$('h2', html).text('is H2');
$('#textarea').val(html.html());`
```

Comment: Can you add a short explanation to your answer, please?